# Private NPM Sinopia registry install error

Tags: node.js, registry, npm

I start working with NPM and I was begging with [Sinopia](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia) as a ***solution for private npm registry*** . So my first command was : `npm install -g sinopia` and I fail with many error so I consult this for [requirement modules](https://www.versioneye.com/nodejs/sinopia/0.4.3). So after installing all of it, the number of error was decreasing, and this what I got:

```
C:\Users\tuto>npm install sinopia
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sinopia
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sinopia
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fs-ext
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fs-ext

> fs-ext@0.3.2 install C:\Users\tuto\node_modules\sinopia\node_modules
\fs-ext
> node-gyp configure build


C:\Users\tuto\node_modules\sinopia\node_modules\fs-ext>node "C:\Progra
m Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bi
n\node-gyp.js" configure build
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.19/node-v0.10.19.tar.gz
gyp http 407 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.19/node-v0.10.19.tar.gz
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: 407 status code downloading tarball
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\install.js:222:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onResponse (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\n
pm\node_modules\request\request.js:812:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:175:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (http.js:1689:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete]
(http.js:120:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1584:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at TCP.onread (net.js:525:27)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\tuto\node_modules\sinopia\node_modules\fs-ext
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.19
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Did anybody can help me please? and tell me where is the problem from?

Thank you so much..

Comment: Could you try the global flag?  `npm install -g sinopia`

Comment: Oui, je suis déjà essayer and it return the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

> gyp http 407 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.19/node-v0.10.19.tar.gz

407 response from a HTTP request means that proxy authentication is required.

Here is how to add username/password credentials:

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxy.company.com:1234
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@proxy.company.com:4567
```

Use quotes around the username if it includes the at-symbol(@) to escape it.

**References**

- [npmrc Man page](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npmrc.html)
- [10 Habits of a Happy Node Hacker](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/3/11/node-habits)
- [Making a node virtualenv](http://unrouted.io/2014/05/03/making-a-node-virtualenv/)
- [Installing Node.js for ACS under current user](http://paulatstepup.blogspot.com/2013/06/installing-nodejs-for-acs-under-local.html)